# Notice: Undefined index: n variable integer

Tags: php

> Notice: Undefined index: n in C:\Users\Marseille\Desktop\Activation
>   W7\UwAmp\www\quezzer\question.php on line 5

this is a code tiped at question.php

```
$number = (int) $_GET['n'];
```

why i have this error! i have not understand!

Comment: Have you checked the variable exists? You shouldn't just assume that the variable will be set. Before doing anything with `$_GET['n']` ensure it exists with something like `if (isset($_GET['n'])) {}`.

Comment: please do you speack french??, i am not english ;)

Comment: Mon francais est assez mauvais, mais... (Google translate au sauvetage?) Avez-vous vérifié la variable existe ? Vous ne devriez pas simplement supposer que la variable sera établi . Avant de faire quelque chose avec `$_GET['n']` assurer qu'il existe quelque chose comme `if (isset($_GET['n'])) {}` . -

Comment: no. the only problem here is the type of the $ number variable is int . I believe that the editor does not recognize the type

Answer (score 4):

Since this is a get variable you're using, from what I understand is that you maybe trying to run the script questions.php directly. Therefore no get variables are set, try

---

**`localhost/yourfolder/questions.php?n=5`**

Comment: non le n=5 est le numéro de la question, et moi j'en 'ai que 3 questions dans la DB. ce que je veux savoir pourquoi il n'accepte pas le int ?

Comment: Ok quels sont les enjeux de votre DB ?

Comment: @HamidMarseille Stop writing your comments in french.. there might be some other users interested in what you wrote, and, of course, there are billions of human beings who don't know french at all..

Comment: @AimalAzmi elle est dédier à enregistrer des questionaire